# Seed mongoDB with mongoose-seed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am using mongoose-seed module to seed my database with some initial data, data is in json file and is not seeded in order from file

```
[{
"model": "User",
"documents": [
  {
    "name": "User1",
    "email": "user1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "User2",
    "email": "user2@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "User3",
    "email": "user3@gmail.com"
  }
]
}]
```

In my db data is seeded in random order, not like user1, user2, user3.

Comment: Why would the order they get inserted to the DB matter?

Comment: Because of ids. I have mongoose-auto-increment plugin and i rely on id to make reference in other model and documents.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Seedgoose](https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/seedgoose), the ultimate seeder with smart reference support.